# Is there a way to force a new update to show up on Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

Since apkmirror.com is not an official source, I would like to download directly from the Google Play Store.

But say, Pokemon Go updates have always been announced, and not available on Google Play but available on apkmirror.com

Wouldn't there actually exist a way to force a new update to show up on Google Play?  Maybe Google Play doesn't want a large amount of traffic to happen all of a sudden, so it does the release worldwide, region by region. But right now is 4am Pacific time. If it is open 4am in Pacific time, it really should not be too much traffic downloading it. If an update can be forced to show up by some advanced user during the non-peak hours (such as 1am to 6am), the traffic really should not be that much.

Comment: Try going to google playstore and search for the app (Pokemon GO) and exit google play, and reopen it and now go ahead search for it (like you want to install it) this time it show the update button (instead of open) I use the same trick to force update  some apps which delay , I guess its just syncing delays

Comment: hm, thank you, to me, this method still shows the open button only

Comment: Probably it may be that the updates won't be uploaded to google servers as yet, because apkmirror and some independent app sites get updates much earlier, since apk mirror is an official trusted store, you could alternatively get an which fetch these updates from apkmirror [apk updater](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-apkupdater-t3444517)

Comment: APKMirror is, I would say, as safe as the Play Store. Never had an issue and well regarded to be safe! Other APK markets, not so much.

Comment: I think at least for Google Play, if anything happens, you have Google to stand behind it (and have Google to guard against it), so if it is backed by one of the top tech companies in the world, then the confidence level can't be much higher than that